# ERRO "object reference not set to an instance of an object error" Visual Studio 2019 - Script View

Tags: sql, visual-studio

Olá, estou a fazer a lição 6 do tutorial do Analysis Services e ao tentar fazer o Script View surge o erro:
"object reference not set to an instance of an object error".
Apenas obtenho esse erro quando vou fazer o script view.

Segue o link do tutorial:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/lesson-6-1-defining-calculated-members?view=sql-server-2014

Segue também um print screen do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem uma solução para o problema?
Obrigada desde já

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, tive que instalar o Visual Studio 2017 e voltar para o 2019.